# Optimization of branch prediction inside hot loop in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, g++, branch-prediction

I have performance critical code which calculates inter-atomic forcefield. It is controled by variables like `bPBC`, `shifts`, `doBonds`, `doPiSigma`, `doPiPiI` which can be switched on and off by user which changes very rarely.

I'm wondering how well can compiler and processor do branch prediction in this situation, and if there is something I can do to make it easier for him?

```
// --------- Bonds Step
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  // loop over bonds of this atom
    int ing = ings[i];
    if (ing < 0) break;
    Vec3d pi = apos[ing];
    Quat4d h;
    h.f.set_sub(pi, pa);
    if (bPBC) {
        [[likely]]
        if (shifts) {
            [[likely]]
            int ipbc = ingC[i];
            h.f.add(shifts[ipbc]);
        } else {
            Vec3i g = invLvec.nearestCell(h.f);
            Vec3d sh = lvec.a * g.x + lvec.b * g.y + lvec.c * g.z;
            h.f.add(sh);
        }
    }
    double l = h.f.normalize();
    h.e = 1 / l;
    hs[i] = h;

    if (ia < ing) {
        [[likely]]
        if (doBonds) {
            [[likely]] E += evalBond(h.f, l - bL[i], bK[i], f1);
            fbs[i].sub(f1);
            fa.add(f1);
        }
        double kpp = Kppi[i];
        if ((doPiPiI) && (ing < nnode) && (kpp > 1e-6)) {
            E += evalPiAling(hpi, pipos[ing], 1., 1., kpp, f1, f2);
            fpi.add(f1);
            fps[i].add(f2);
        }
    }

    double ksp = Kspi[i];
    if (doPiSigma && (ksp > 1e-6)) {
        E += evalAngleCos(hpi, h.f, 1., h.e, ksp, piC0, f1, f2);
        fpi.add(f1);
        fa.sub(f2);
        fbs[i].add(f2);
    }
}
```

Additional questions:

- The variables  `bPBC`, `shifts`, `doBonds`, `doPiSigma`, `doPiPiI` are class properties, so they are allocated on heap. Would it help speed of if evaluation and branch precitions if I make a copy to `const` local variable in front of the loop? For example like this:

```
const bool bPBC_ = bPBC;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){ // loop over bonds
    if(bPBC_){ ... }
    ...
}
```

- I compile it with `g++` and I get warnings that the `[[likely]]` attributes are ignored. Should I be concerned? Or is it just because compiler consider this branch likely by default so the attribute is redundant?

```
/home/prokophapala/git/FireCore/cpp/common/molecular/MMFFsp3_loc.h:320:21: warning: ‘likely’ attribute ignored [-Wattributes]
  320 |                 int ipbc = ingC[i];
```

Comment: How about making multiple versions of the function at compile time using templates and `if constexpr` and deciding which version to call higher up in the call chain ? ie: before the tight loop even begins, or do those variables change inside the loop ?

Comment: You need to show the entire code for this question to be answerable, or better a shortened version that exihibts the same problem. As to your other questions, class data members are not allocated on the heap, they are allocated wherever your object of that class type is allocated. This may very well be on the stack. Making local copies of the controlling properties may help, but `const` will not make a difference there. And your `[[likely]]` attributes are placed incorrectly, they should go before the curly brace.

Comment: @AhmedAEK you are right, that would be perhaps best performancewise but the higher I move the decision the more complicated and obfuscated the code gets. I try to keep some tradeoff between speed and transparency of debugging

Comment: Optimizing compilers can generate multiple version of the loop when the condition inside is independent of the loop. However, it is unfortunately not rare for mainstream compiler to fail to do such a basic optimization.

Comment: Still, this is not so critical because a branch that is always taken is relatively cheap on modern mainstream x86-64 CPUs. Branch like this can prevent the code to be vectorized but I do not expect it to be vectorized anyway (due to the break and the memory layout). What matters a lot is branches having an outcome that is hard to *predict* (e.g. changing from one iteration to another with a rather random pattern).

Comment: *"class properties, so they are allocated on heap"* Objects can be allocated on the stack in C++. This is actually not rare. Whether the object are in stack or heap does not really matter for performance. What matter is that if they are in the cache when they need to be loaded from memory. Heap allocation is more expensive but once allocated, it does not make a big difference. Note that stack objects tends to be more in the cache than heap ones in practice though (due to the inherent temporal locality of the stack).

Comment: Thus, copying field should not be beneficial. In fact GCC love removing copies like this in practice, even when they are useful for performance :/ ... It can be useful for performance when GCC assume the object state can change between iterations (because this is not easy to detect, especially due to a possible aliasing with other variable of the same type).

Comment: I strongly advise to profile your code using a *profiler* tracking *hardware counters* (especially PEBS ones) so to check if the conditions are actually an issue and find out the actual bottleneck. Here, modifying the code to make it more SIMD friendly would certainly make it significantly faster, but this is clearly not something trivial to do (significant impact on the code). SIMD is the key to get good performance on modern and future systems.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, one way to optimize this is to create specialized implementations for each flag combination. Doing this manually is tedious but we don't need to.

[`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) is very useful when implementing this. The idea is very simple: We turn each flag value into a type (handily available as [`std::bool_constant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant) since C++17) and move them into variants. Then let `std::visit` dispatch all variations of parameter combinations to a [generic lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

The `bool_constants` that are passed to the lambda have the same effect as a `constexpr bool`. So at this point the dead-code elimination of the compiler can do the rest. This would even work without `if constexpr` if you ever need to backport this to C++14 or 11.

You did not post a complete enough code sample, so I just demonstrate this on some generic code. Just move your actual code into the `impl` lambda.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <variant>


void implBPC();
void implShifts();
void implBonds();
void implPiSigma();
void implPiPiI();


void hot(bool bPBC, bool shifts, bool doBonds, bool doPiSigma, bool doPiPiI)
{
    using boolVar = std::variant<std::false_type, std::true_type>;
    auto impl = [](auto bPBC, auto shifts, auto doBonds,
                   auto doPiSigma, auto doPiPiI) {
        if constexpr (bPBC)
            implBPC();
        if constexpr (shifts)
            implShifts();
        if constexpr (doBonds)
            implBonds();
        if constexpr (doPiSigma)
            implPiSigma();
        if constexpr (doPiPiI)
            implPiPiI();
    };
    auto toBoolVar = [](bool flag) -> boolVar {
        if(flag)
            return std::true_type{};
        return std::false_type{};
    };
    std::visit(impl, toBoolVar(bPBC), toBoolVar(shifts), toBoolVar(doBonds),
               toBoolVar(doPiSigma), toBoolVar(doPiPiI));
}
```

One thing that you need to look out for: If you call functions inside your code, the compiler will now see many more call sites (one for each implementation). It may decide to no longer inline calls it did before.

If the `visit` call turns out to have too much overhead, we can instead do it once when we set the flags to decide between various abstract implementations. Then we just need to do a virtual method call when we use it later instead of checking 5 boolean flags.

```cpp
// abstract interface
struct HotFunctor
{
    virtual ~HotFunctor() = default;
    virtual void operator()() = 0;
};

// template-specialized implementation
template<bool bPBC, bool shifts, bool doBonds, bool doPiSigma, bool doPiPiI>
struct HotImpl final: HotFunctor
{
    virtual void operator()() override
    {
        if constexpr (bPBC)
            implBPC();
        if constexpr (shifts)
            implShifts();
        if constexpr (doBonds)
            implBonds();
        if constexpr (doPiSigma)
            implPiSigma();
        if constexpr (doPiPiI)
            implPiPiI();
    }
};

void hot(bool bPBC, bool shifts, bool doBonds, bool doPiSigma, bool doPiPiI)
{
    // select which implementation to use
    using boolVar = std::variant<std::false_type, std::true_type>;
    auto makeImpl = [](auto bPBC, auto shifts, auto doBonds,
                   auto doPiSigma, auto doPiPiI)
            -> std::unique_ptr<HotFunctor> {
        return std::make_unique<HotImpl<
                bPBC, shifts, doBonds, doPiSigma, doPiPiI>>();
    };
    auto toBoolVar = [](bool flag) -> boolVar {
        if(flag)
            return std::true_type{};
        return std::false_type{};
    };
    std::unique_ptr<HotFunctor> impl = std::visit(
            makeImpl, toBoolVar(bPBC), toBoolVar(shifts), toBoolVar(doBonds),
            toBoolVar(doPiSigma), toBoolVar(doPiPiI));
    // use repeatedly
    for(...)
        (*impl)();
}
```

An `std::function` should also work well for this, as would a plain function pointer to a template function if you are looking for the lowest possible call overhead.